# Two dimensional array expandable in all directions

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, game-physics

Gday everybody,

I'm just trying to program the so called "life game". Forgot who invented it, but I find it pretty interesting. Please DO NOT post any links related to programming the game, as it would destroy my motivation ;)

The essential part of it is the playground. I need a two dimensional array, which is expandable in all directions.

E.g. I've got an array with 10*10 Fields in the beginning. I need to be able to add new fields in the direction of array[-1][-1] as well as in the direction of array[11][11] at the same time. I even need to be able to add a new item to field array[-1][10] or array[10][-10]. I need to be able to access the array into all possible 2D directions.

By the same time of writing this post, I just got an idea: What about having four arrays pointing towards all directions NORTH, EAST, SOUTH and WEST? Just having all arrays put next to each other, virtually pointing in the specified direction. Just like the example below. All Arrays put together form my playground. Would it be efficient, or are there simpler ways?

```
[][][] | [][][]
[][][] | [][][]
[][][] | [][][]
_______|_______
[][][] | [][][]
[][][] | [][][]
[][][] | [][][]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a link to the rules of this game? I am confused by your explaination.

Comment: I suggest to create a grid class with periodic boundary conditions, such that `x=-1; grid.set(x, y);` equals `x = -1 + L; grid.set(x, y);`.

Comment: Imagine a change in game requirements: we need 3dimensions in place of 2dimensions. Do you still think that array is the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using primitive arrays, expanding the matrix with a fixed number of cells could look like this:

```
boolean[][] gameBoard = new boolean[3][3];

public boolean[][] expandMatrixBy(boolean[][] matrix, int number) {
  int oldSize = matrix.length;
  int newSize = oldSize + 2 * number;
  boolean[][] result = new boolean[newSize][newSize];

  // Assume new cells should be dead, i.e. false..
  for (int row = number; row < oldSize + number; row++) {
    for (int col = number; col < oldSize + number; col++) {
      // ..copy only the existing cells into new locations.
      result[row][col] = matrix[row - number][col - number];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

// Calling this on a 3x3 matrix will produce 5x5 matrix, expanded by 1 on each side.
gameBoard = expandMatrixBy(gameBoard, 1);
```

And it's **John Conway's Game of Life** :-)

**OPTION:**
This solution can be customized to enable expansion on selected sides with something like this:

```
enum Side { Left, Right, Top, Bottom };

public boolean[][] expandMatrixBy(boolean[][] matrix, int number, Set<Side> sides) {
  int oldSize = matrix.length;
  int newSize = oldSize + number * sides.size();
  boolean[][] result = new boolean[newSize][newSize];

  for (Side side : sides) {
    switch(side) {
      case Left:
        // Add number of columns on the left.

      case Right:
        // Add "number" of columns on the right.
    }
  }
  return result;
}

Set<Side> expandOnTheseSides = EnumSet.of(Side.Left, Side.Top);
gameBoard = expandMatrixBy(gameBoard, 1, expandOnTheseSides);
```

Good luck.

Comment: I don't get why you're multiplying the number by 2 in newSize. Though it's a good approach I guess :P My playground would be limited to two sides, though.

Comment: When you said "expandable in all directions" I thought you meant expand in all directions by the same number of columns at the same time. The last line in the code will add 1 row/column on each side, that's why you multiply `number` by 2 because there are two sides on each axis.

Comment: Ah I see. Yeah that's exactly what I ment. Thanks bud [:

Comment: I have just added an optional improvement in case you need partial expansion. `boolean[][]` might not be a good choice, but if you don't plan on expanding too often and by too much this will be good.

Comment: yeh kind of you. The problem I'm still facing is the copying of all the elements of the source array. takes alot of time and resources, depending on the size of the source array. Well, gotta do some more homework then. Thanks for helping me out here!